# wxWidgets compilation error (fatal error LNK1120: 26 unresolved externals)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, wxwidgets

I'm trying to build a minimal wxWidgets application with as small a size as is easily possible. (Easily for me, that is).

It's a Hello World GUI program that doesn't do anything else. So, to my knowledge, I only need wxBase and wxCore, which I built using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition in /MT mode.

My application looks like this:

```
#include "wx/app.h"
#include "wx/frame.h"
#include "wx/menu.h"
#include "wx/statusbr.h"
#include "wx/msgdlg.h"

class MyApp: public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

class MyFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:

    MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);

    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

    DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE()
};

enum
{
    ID_Quit = 1,
    ID_About,
};

BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(ID_Quit, MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(ID_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
END_EVENT_TABLE()

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)

bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame( _("Hello World"), wxPoint(50, 50),
                                  wxSize(450,340) );
    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);
    return true;
} 

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size)
: wxFrame( NULL, -1, title, pos, size )
{
    wxMenu *menuFile = new wxMenu;

    menuFile->Append( ID_About, _("&About...") );
    menuFile->AppendSeparator();
    menuFile->Append( ID_Quit, _("E&xit") );

    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar;
    menuBar->Append( menuFile, _("&File") );

    SetMenuBar( menuBar );

    CreateStatusBar();
    SetStatusText( _("Welcome to wxWidgets!") );
}

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    Close(TRUE);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxMessageBox( _("This is a wxWidgets Hello world sample"),
                  _("About Hello World"),
                  wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION, this);
}
```

Its a near exact copy of the Hello World program in the [wxWidgets documentation](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hello.htm). I just changed the include files. Replacing them with `#include "wx/wx.h"` doesn't solve the problem either by the way.

The build errors I get are:

```
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall wxApp::Initialize(int &,wchar_t * *)" (?Initialize@wxApp@@UAE_NAAHPAPA_W@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: void __thiscall wxStringBase::InitWith(wchar_t const *,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?InitWith@wxStringBase@@IAEXPB_WII@Z)
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t const * const wxEmptyString" (?wxEmptyString@@3PB_WB)
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t const * const wxStatusLineNameStr" (?wxStatusLineNameStr@@3QB_WB)
test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "wchar_t const * const wxFrameNameStr" (?wxFrameNameStr@@3QB_WB)
C:\Users\microsoft\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\wxAnother\Release\wxAnother.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

I was going to include all the changes I made to the project's properties, but I noticed that all these errors have something to do with `wchar_t`, which might be enough for somebody to tell me what's causing the error.

What's causing these pesky unresolved external errors and how do I solve the problem (get rid of them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you compiled wxWidgets libs as Multi-Threaded DLL and your project is Multi-Threaded. Or (since all errors have string params in description) your wx libs are compiled with Multi-Byte character set and app with Unicode or vise versa.

You also haven't mentioned which wx libs you mentioned in LInker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

Comment: The culprit was the Unicode setting. I had compiled wxWdigets without using Unicode, but my app's settings had Unicode. Changed that setting in the project, and problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to outsmart the compiler/linker.

Why?

If there is a genuine reason for you to need a small executable size then wxWidgets is not the way to go.  Take a look at FLTK http://fltk.org/

Comment: What makes you think that? I'm including only the required wxWidgets libraries to keep executable size to a minimum, the same thing hundreds of other users have tried to do too.

Comment: Several decades of experience make me think this :-)  About a hundred years ago when compilers and linkers where simpler affairs I used to spend lots of time worrying about how to optimize their use.  Nowadays, not so much.

Comment: Apologies if I sounded rude. But honestly, I've read this quite a few times now, is size really not such a big deal now? I moved from Qt to wxWidgets simply because the dynamically linked Qt application was around 5 MB which I thought was just too much. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: I assume you mean statically linked  ( not using DLLs )  Well, yes, 5 MB is kind of big.  My wxWidgets apps, including all the libraries, need about 2MB of disk space.  However, I would never learn a new GUI framework just to save a few meg of disk space.  I just bought a 16 GIG USB key for less than $10.

Comment: No, I meant using DLLs. Incorrect terminology? As to learning a new framework, I have a massive advantage there, having not used any framework to develop anything more than a teeny tiny application. Also, Qt 5 makes things even bigger. And finally, I wanted a native look and feel on Windows, so I can't use FLTK. Any further advice?